# How to display all subcategories in a hierarchy?

Tags: python-3.x, pelican

I'm trying to create a hierarchical menu with all the categories. However, whatever I do, I can't create a hierarchical display of all the subcategories. I've set the PATH_METADATA to use the folders for category management.
pelican=4.5.4, pelican-more-categories=0.1.0

I have this folder structure:

- Universidad

  - Idiomas

    - Español
    - Rumano
  - Culturas

    - España

      - Andalucía

        - Sevilla
        - Málaga
        - Almería
      - Castilla La Mancha
      - Galicia

        - Santiago de Compostela
      - Navarra
    - México

      - Jalisco

        - Guadalajara
        - Tequila
    - Rumanía

      - Oltenia

        - Craiova
      - Muntenia

        - Târgoviște
      - Dobrogea

Can somebody give me an example of displaying all those categories in a template?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how [Adam Tindale](http://www.adamtindale.com) does it, he makes the source code [public](https://github.com/drart/adamtindale.com).

Here is 1 example from his base.html template.

```
  {% for category, articles in categories %}
  <li class="menu-category"><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{category.url}}">{{ category }}</a>
  <ul>
      {% for article in articles  %}
      <li><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul> 
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is a useful link, but not an answer. This lists the articles inside the categories. I need a hierarchical list of categories, indented, similar to the list in the question.

Comment: If this is not an answer, then I'm afraid nobody will be able to answer your question for the simple fact that for example you haven't specified how you've achieved those hierarchy of categories technically.  This is an indication of how a hierarchy in the menu can be done, I don't think it's unreasonable to expect that you adapt the proposed idea to your specific need.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it with enough clarity. The point here is that I need help to show just descendents, not every previous category shortname. For example, when you hover on Spain, it should show Andalusia, Navarra, etc. - not Spain/Andalusia, Spain/Navarra...